# Prevent root user to switch user to any Disabled AD user

Tags: active-directory, sssd

root user is able to "su" to an user which is Disabled in AD.
As it's a security concern, need to prevent root user to su to any AD users, who is disabled in AD.
It should check the user status in AD before switching to it.

Comment: Most people would says that someone gaining root access is already a bigger "security concern." Anyway, root is supposed to be able to switch to any user. It can even ***switch to users that don't even exist***. You could go to the extreme of writing a su wrapper or enabling SELinux/AppArmor filtering of the setuid syscall to a list of allowed users, but root could just disable those security features. Furthermore, a root user doing "su" to any other user is called dropping privileges and good for security. Please reconsider your security model

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo